# How to refactor deprecated set-env in github action

Tags: deprecated, github-actions, setenv

I have a github action that runs set-env, now as it is deprecated as mentioned [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/), how can refactor the following code?

```
 run: echo "::set-env name=BRANCH_NAME::$(echo ${GITHUB_HEAD_REF} | tr -cd '[:alnum:]\n' | cut -c -30 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable):

```yaml
 run: echo "BRANCH_NAME=$(echo ${GITHUB_HEAD_REF} | tr -cd '[:alnum:]\n' | cut -c -30 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Additionally, instead of messing up with `tr` and `cut` you can get the branch name in a more convenient way using the [`GITHUB_REF` built-in variable](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables). It will simplify the script to

```yaml
 run: echo "BRANCH_NAME=${GITHUB_REF##*/}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: This is helpful, I'd also been struggling to know how to read the documentation.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you very much, 1st command works as expected.
Regarding simplified script , it caused that branch name to equal HEAD !! , am i missing something ? can you elaborate  a bit more how the simplified one works?

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems there was a mistake in the original solution. I made a correction already. Please try again with the modified approach.